# PHP : Check If Two Column-Values are Correct in SQL Table

Tags: php, sql

I want to check an SQL table if two column values are both equal to specified values using PHP. My table looks like this:

```
             my_db 
------------------------------------------
 code       | user | email               |
------------------------------------------
 10314343   |  20  | example@example.com |
 13423434   |  22  | example@example.com |
 11342434   |  40  | example@example.com |
```

This is my PHP, although not working:

```
// Set variables
$tbl_name = mydb;
$matchCode   = "10314343"
$matchUserID = "20"

// Query matchCode and MatchUSerID on db
$getName = "SELECT FROM $tbl_name WHERE user ='$matchUserID' ";
$queryName = mysql_query($getName);

// Query matchCode and MatchUSerID on db
$getCode = "SELECT FROM $tbl_name WHERE code ='$matchCode' ";
$queryCode = mysql_query($getCode);


// If these match 
if($queryCode == 1 || $queryName == 1) {
  echo "The User ID and Code Value Both Match";
}
```

I'm not sure whether this is the best way of doing things. I was thinking you might be able to get the entire row data by "user" ID, and then query that row for the "code" value. Although I'm unsure how to do that.

What I'm trying to achieve is an sql query that checks if my variable  matches the data of "code" for in the row of `$matchUserID`.

Comment: `SELECT code FROM $tbl_name WHERE user ='$matchUserID' AND code ='$matchCode'`

Answer (score 2):

You're not selecting anything, also if you want to check if both values are the same in 1 row, you should combine the queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl_name WHERE user ='$matchUserID' AND code = '$matchCode'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$hasMatch = mysql_result($result, 0);
if ($hasMatch) {
    ...
}
```

Since you're only interested in knowing whether a row exists in the table, you can use `COUNT(*)` to only return the number of rows that were found.

Comment: I'm getting "Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter to be resource on the hasMatch line.

Comment: You need to execute the query before you can access the result

Comment: Stll getting "result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..." on line $hasMatch.

Comment: Then the query probably isn't being executed. I've changed to code to show the mysql error if the query fails.